# xampp ubuntu laravel The stream or file "/storage/logs/laravel log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, xampp

installed laravel on my xampp installation on ubuntu. opened it in browser. got the error:

> The stream or file /storage/logs/laravel log could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

how to fix? (i've already found an answer, will post right now)

Comment: usually laravel is installed on homestead, on vagrant, thus all the answers are about these platforms, and i added the value - the answer about laravel on xampp+ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the user under which the apache runs doesn't have access to the folder. in xampp on ubuntu, the user of main apache process is `root`. but apache workers run under `daemon` user. the solution is to grant `daemon` access to the `/storage` dir. (if you'll only grant to `/storage/logs` than you'll fix this error, but the same error will occur with sibling dirs. thus the `storage` itself folder:

```
sudo chown -R daemon /path-to-your-project/storage
```

now the `daemon` user has access to this folder (and you don't but do you need it?
if you have better solutions, please feel free to share them here!

Answer (score 0):

Add to `composer.json`

```
    "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
          "chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache",
          "chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache"
     ]
}
```

Then run composer install or update solve your issue

Comment: did you try this yourself on ubuntu+xampp? i've just tried and got the error: `chgrp: changing group of 'storage/framework/testing/.gitignore': Operation not permitted`. that's because composer is run under user privileges, not as a root (and composer docs strongly discourages against running it as root) but the `chgrp` command requires root privileges. therefore, that won't work

Comment: btw, why at all should i change the group to `www-data`? in xampp on ubuntu, apache is run under `root` and `daemon` users. i've just run `groups daemon` and it shows that `daemon` user doesn't belong to any `www-data` group. what is this `www-data`? could you explain this?

Comment: btw, i've just tried running `sudo chown -R www-data storage/` directly and you know what - it didn't help either.

Comment: and `sudo chgrp -R www-data storage/` doesn't help either

Comment: The web user group is www-data so you change the ownership of web directory file into www-data ownership. Try both commands inside your composer or from your terminal and work fine.

Comment: by writing "i've just tried running [the command] directly" i meant that i've run it "from my terminal" and it didn't work at all. and when i look into ubuntu's process monitor, i see that i have one `/opt/lampp/bin/httpd` running under the `root` user and several (workers) - under `daemon` user. and neither `root` nor `daemon` aren't in the `www-data` group. i know that by running `groups daemon` and `groups root` in my terminal which return `root : root` and `daemon : daemon` respectively. so no, that didn't work at all. did you tried that on your physical ubuntu+xampp? (not `homestead` vm)